# Python - Race Results - Issues sorting dictionay entries and printing out data in particular form

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary

FYI I am new to python and there could be a more efficient way to produce the desired results. Please feel free to suggest an alternative method.

Problem 1 - 
I cannot figure out a way to add "1st Place:, 2nd Place:, etc." to output 1

Problem 2 - 
I cannot figure out why, in output 2, I cannot get the time to print.

```
import os

os.system('cls')

#**********************************************
# The goal of this script is to collect both a racers name and finish time. When the last
# racers data is entered the script will order the names of racers (i.e. First, Second,
# Third) based on time (less time is better.) and print the ordered results to the screen.
# The race times will be entered as integers.

#**********************************************

# Sample input:

# What is the first racers name: Larry 

# What is the first racers time: 12

# What is the second racers name: Moe 

# What is the second racers time: 9

# What is the third racers name: Curly 

# What is the third racers time: 20


# Sample output:

# 1st Place: Moe

# 2nd Place: Larry

# 3rd Place: Curly

#**********************************************


print ('\n')

print ('\n')


# Enter the first racers name

racer_name_1 = input("Enter racer number one's name: ")


# Enter the first racers time 

racer_time_1 = int(input("Enter racer number one's time: "))


# Enter the Second racers name

racer_name_2 = input("Enter racer number two's name: ")


# Enter the Second racers time 

racer_time_2 = int(input("Enter racer number two's time: "))


# Enter the Third racers name

racer_name_3 = input("Enter racer number three's name: ")


# Enter the Third racers time 

racer_time_3 = int(input("Enter racer number three's time: "))


# Create the race results dictionary

raceList = {racer_name_1:"racer_time_1", racer_name_2:"racer_time_2", 
racer_name_3:"racer_time_3"}


print ('\n')

# This is output 1
for value in sorted(raceList, reverse=True):
print (value)


print ('\n')

# This is output 2
print (raceList)


print ('\n')

print ('\n')
```

Comment: you should put your inputs in  try except, if a user enters anything other than an int your program will crash

Comment: So much vertical whitespace...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 2**

You don't need quotes here, or the values will be interpreted as string literals, which they are

```
raceList = {racer_name_1:"racer_time_1",
            racer_name_2:"racer_time_2", 
            racer_name_3:"racer_time_3"}
```

Just use your variables as the values

```
raceList = {racer_name_1: racer_time_1,
            racer_name_2: racer_time_2, 
            racer_name_3: racer_time_3}
```

**Question 1**

Make a list of tuples like (name, time)

```
racers = [(i, raceList[i]) for i in raceList]
```

Sort that list by their times

```
places = sorted(racers, key = lambda i: int(i[1]))
```

Then print out their names based on the position in the sorted list.

```
print('1st Place: {}'.format(places[0][0]))
print('2nd Place: {}'.format(places[1][0]))
print('3rd Place: {}'.format(places[2][0]))
```

Comment: "for value in sorted(raceList, reverse=True):" <-- this seem to work when I run the program. Am i missing something?

Comment: Thank you. I removed quotes around racer_time* and I am now able to see the times. Problem 2 has been solved :)

Comment: @ChadYoung Regarding your first question, that was my mistake, that would be equivalent to `sorted(raceList.keys())` which will produce a `list` which is sortable. You are correct, that will work.

Comment: Thank you, I used your suggestions and my program is working great. No all that I need to do is lookup why your suggestions worked :)

Comment: Here are two search terms that you could look up, they are great tools to add to your Python toolbelt: "list comprehension" and "lambda expression". If you master those, you will have a much easier time.